# CSS: Scaling an image to 50% without a gap

Tags: css

This should be pretty simple but I am getting @2x images (twice the size for retina) for my site and I need to scaled them how to 50% for the site. I originally tried

```
height:50%;
width:auto;
```

but it scaled it down to half the size of the container. Then I tried

```
transform: scale(0.5)
```

which worked but left a huge gap (the difference in the original size of the image) above and below image.

What is the best way to show an image at half the size without causing a visual issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use translateX and translateY for remove gup `transform: scale(0.5) translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%)`

See example: https://jsfiddle.net/denisstukalov/bpwuhtfc/

Comment: Thank you! Once I removed the transformX, it worked like a charm!